# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4' still after installing all the files

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I recently got a new laptop and had to reinstall all the programs I was using on my old laptop so that I could do my Python programming for University. We are using Qt Designer to make our GUIs along with Python IDLE to do the coding.

I have currently have Python 3.4 and PyQt4 (4.11.4) installed which were the same versions I had on my old laptop. I got my downloads from Riverside.

After designing them in Qt Designer, I then convert them from .ui to .py using cmd prmpt and have no issues doing so. However, when I try to run the code it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QtDesigner\Assignment8Question1.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

I tried to run programs that used to work fine on my old laptop but they still have the same issue. Have I installed PyQt incorrectly or what am I missing?

I have seen some threads similar but none hitting the jackpot. This is driving me insane so thanks in advance.

Comment: You can give more details of your installation of pyqt4.

Comment: @eyllanesc I downloaded the file PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.7-x64 from Riverbank (not Riverside, my mistake in the post). I just followed the install instructions and that was it. I didn't do any of the shell or cmd installing as I found the correct file I needed online. It was the same steps I used on my old laptop and I didn't have this issue.

Comment: In your new laptop you have Qt4 installed, then you executed python configure.py, make and make install. I am right?

Comment: @eyllanescI have not done that. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I downloaded the binary file and not the zip folder.

Comment: You can indicate the link of your download, please

Comment: Sure, https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/

Comment: Look in the folder where you have installed python, inside it there must be a folder called lib, inside the previous one another call site-packages and verify that in this last folder you will find pyqt4. `/path/of/your/python/lib/site-packages/PyQt4`

Comment: yes: D:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4

Comment: I could help you install it through teamviewer

Comment: give me a second to just download it. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Also uninstall PyQt4

Comment: I have uninstalled PyQt4 and have installed teamviewer. What next?

Comment: @eyllanesc You are an absolute star, thank you for all your help!